# return full name after login in java

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to display a logged in user full name after login but need some direction.I already validated the user against the database but it only returns the email from the login.How to i get information about the logged in user. I have three classes the LoginDAO,Session and managedbean,the loginDAO includes the query to fetch the required information from the database.

```
  public class Users {
  private int userid;
  private String fname;
  private String lname;
  private String email;
  private String password;
  private String profileimg;
  Profile uprofile = new Profile();

public Profile getUprofile() {
    return uprofile;
}

public void setUprofile(Profile uprofile) {
    this.uprofile = uprofile;
}

public String getProfileimg() {
    return profileimg;
}

public void setProfileimg(String profileimg) {
    this.profileimg = profileimg;
}

public int getUserid() {
    return userid;
}

public void setUserid(int userid) {
    this.userid = userid;
}

public String getFname() {
    return fname;
}

public void setFname(String fname) {
    this.fname = fname;
}

public String getLname() {
    return lname;
}

public void setLname(String lname) {
    this.lname = lname;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

}

```
    public class LoginDAO {        
    public static Users validate (String user,String password) throws SQLException{
        Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    Users validUser = null;

        try{
            con = DataConnect.getConnection();
            ps = con.prepareStatement("Select fname,lname,email, password from  users where email = ? and password = MD5(?)");
            ps.setString(1, user);
            ps.setString(2, password);

            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            if(rs.next()) {  
             validUser = new Users();              
              validUser.setFname(rs.getString("fname"));
               validUser.setLname(rs.getString("lname"));
               return true;
            return   validUser;
                    }
    }catch (SQLException ex){
    System.out.println("Login error -->" + 
            ex.getMessage());
    return null;
}finally{
    DataConnect.close(con);
}
return validUser;
```

}
}

This is the managed bean
        @ManagedBean(name="loginbean")
        @SessionScoped
        public class LoginBean implements Serializable {
        private String fname;
        private String pwd;
        private String msg;
        private String user;

```
    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    public String getPwd() {
        return pwd;
    }

    public void setPwd(String pwd) {
        this.pwd = pwd;
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
```

This method calls the loginDAO and matches it against the user input and starts the session.

```
public String validateUsernamePassword() throws SQLException {
Users validUser = LoginDAO.validate(user, pwd); 
    if (validUser != null) {
        HttpSession session = SessionUtils.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("username", validUser.getEmail());
   session.setAttribute("firstname", validUser.getFname());
        return "feed";
    } else {

        return "login";
    }
}
 //logout event, invalidate session
public String logout() {
    HttpSession session = SessionUtils.getSession();
    session.invalidate();
    return "login";
}

  <h:form>
            <p>Welcome <h:outputText id="username" value="#    
      {loginbean.user}"/></p>
            <h:outputText id="firstname" value="#{loginbean.fname}"/>
    <h:commandLink action="#{loginbean.logout}" value="Logout">  
   </h:commandLink>


</h:form>
```

Comment: Please fix your code formatting.

Comment: and what is the problem with your program ?

Answer (score 1):

your methode `LoginDAO.validate(user, pwd);` returns a boolean(true or false) and not a User-Object.

AND here:

```
if(rs.next()){

   rs.getString("fname");
   rs.getString("lname");
   return true;
}
```

you get the **"fname"** and **"lname"** attributes from the resultset, but you don't save them anywhere!

you may change this method this way:

```
public static UserObject validate (String user,String password) throws SQLException{
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    UserObject validUser = null;
    try{
        con = DataConnect.getConnection();
       ps = con.prepareStatement("Select fname,lname,email, password from  users where email = ? and password = MD5(?)");
        ps.setString(1, user);
        ps.setString(2, password);

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

                    if(rs.next()){
                   validUser = new UserObject();
                   validUser.setFname(rs.getString("fname"));
                   validUser.setLname(rs.getString("lname"));
                   validUser.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                   // ...etc.
                        return validUser;
                    }
    }catch (SQLException ex){
        System.out.println("Login error -->" + 
                ex.getMessage());
        return null;
    }finally{
        DataConnect.close(con);
    }
    return validUser;
}
```

then you check if its a valid Login this way:

```
public String validateUsernamePassword() throws SQLException { 
   UserObject validUser = LoginDAO.validate(user, pwd); 
   if (validUser != null ) { 
       HttpSession session = SessionUtils.getSession();         
       session.setAttribute("username", validUser.getUsername()); 
       session.setAttribute("firstname",validUser.getFname()); 
       return "feed"; 
   } else {
        return "login";
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi Rami thanks for the help,it much appreciated the login works fine but it does not display the user first name

Comment: read my answer once again please! Your validate method returns only true or false, you don't save the fetched data to any object/variable, and in your validateUsernamePassword, where do you get the "fname" value? just try to follow my example and rewrite it to fit your Needs/implementations. it should then work. or you update your Question and provide full Code of your Beans/Objects ...etc.